# Should "writing" be allowed as a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

Using the [`[programming]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming) tag is discouraged on stackoverflow.

Using the [`[apple]`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/apple-inc/synonyms) tag is discouraged on apple.se.

Using the [`[english]`](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) tag is discouraged on english.se.

For the above cases, the theory is that each particular tag should apply to *every* question on the site—that is, if there's a question where it doesn't apply, that question probably isn't a good fit for the site in general.

In the spirit of the above, is there a reason for the [`[writing]`](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing) tag here?

Answer (score 11):

It seems like, if we follow the logic as you've laid it out, there is no reason for the `[writing]` tag to be used here. That seems logical to me, if it's on this site is be default about writing.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to agree, as well. Every question on here is about writing in some way, shape, or form. It's too tempting for people to just select "Writing" as a tag and move on - which is incredibly unhelpful. I would like to see more specific tags used.

Answer (score -3):

Just to play Devil's Advocate, I can see one use of the [writing](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing) tag.

New users cannot create new tags, but also cannot post a question unless it has at least one tag.  The writing tag could be a useful placeholder until a higher-rep user comes along and re-tags the question with something more relevant and specific.

Not that I necessarily agree with this, but it's good to develop all sides of the argument.